# Where to include toolbar layout in FrameLayout having ListView and Progressbar

Tags: c#, android, xml, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have a Frame Layout which contains List View and Progress bar. Now i am trying to add Navigation Drawer with toolbar layout In Frame Layout with List View and Progress bar.

But problem is that when i use   `<include layout="@layout/toolbar" />` Progressbar doesn't show up and List View goes behind toolbar layout.

Its Looks Like This :

[image]

To work around this :

- I removed `<include layout="@layout/toolbar" />`
- Used `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar`
- Removed `var toolbar = FindViewById<V7Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);`
- Removed `SetSupportActionBar(toolbar);`
- Removed toolbar param from `var drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, Resource.String.drawer_open, Resource.String.drawer_close);`

But with this i lost drawer open-close button (Three horizontal lines).

Now it looks like this -

[image]

Can anybody please help me with adding ' Navigation Drawer with toolbar layout In Frame Layout with List View and Progress bar.' or Just Get back drawer button.

Here is the xaml code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

       <!-- <include layout="@layout/toolbar" /> -->  
    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="@android:style/Widget.DeviceDefault.ProgressBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:visibility="gone" />
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/feedList"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp" />
       <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header" />
  </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Theme Styles :

```
<!-- Navigation Drawer Theme-->
  <style name="Theme.DesignDemo" parent="Base.Theme.DesignDemo">

  </style>
  <style name="Base.Theme.DesignDemo" 
  parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">#2196F3</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#1976D2</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/window_background</item>
  </style>
```

Drawer activity code :

```
  using Android.Support.V7.App;
   using Android.Support.V4.Widget;
   using V7Toolbar = Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar;
   using Android.Support.Design.Widget;

   [Activity (Label = "ANews", Icon = "@drawable/newsicon", Theme = 
    "@style/Theme.DesignDemo")]
     public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
     {

        DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
        NavigationView navigationView;

       protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle){
        base.OnCreate (bundle);




        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.FeedsList);


        drawerLayout = FindViewById<DrawerLayout>(Resource.Id.drawer_layout);
        // Create ActionBarDrawerToggle button and add it to the toolbar  
        //var toolbar = FindViewById<V7Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);
        //SetSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        var drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, Resource.String.drawer_open, Resource.String.drawer_close);
        drawerLayout.SetDrawerListener(drawerToggle);
        drawerToggle.SyncState();
        navigationView = FindViewById<NavigationView>(Resource.Id.nav_view);
        setupDrawerContent(navigationView); //Calling Function  

    }
     void setupDrawerContent(NavigationView navigationView)
    {
        navigationView.NavigationItemSelected += (sender, e) =>
        {
            e.MenuItem.SetChecked(true);
            drawerLayout.CloseDrawers();
        };
    }
    public override bool OnCreateOptionsMenu(IMenu menu)
    {
        navigationView.InflateMenu(Resource.Menu.nav_menu); //Navigation Drawer Layout Menu Creation  
        return true;
    }
```

toolbar.axml code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:id="@+id/main_content"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" />
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Usually issues like this are due to not adding the control to an existing control (or the wrong control).  I don't see any add methods in the posted code.

Comment: Please post your toolbar.aml code.

Comment: @jdweng, i think you haven't read the whole description/code. I have already added   'SetSupportActionBar(toolbar);'  code in drawer activity. But for workaround i have commented it.

Comment: @YorkShen, I have added toolbar code  as you requested. Please let me know if you get any solution.

Comment: In your toolbar.axml, modify your CoordinatorLayout  height property from android:layout_height="match_parent" to android:layout_height="wrap_content", then try again.

Comment: @YorkShen, Sorry no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Progressbar doesn't show up and List View goes behind toolbar layout.

Put your `ProgressBar`, `ListView` and `Toolbar` in a `LinearLayout` or a `RelativeLayout`, because as the [document](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html) said:
`FrameLayout` should be used to hold a single child view, because it organize child `views` in a way that children overlapping each other.

And modify your code in your toolbar.axml:

```
 <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
    ...
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">//From match_parent to wrap_content, when the property is match_parent, it means that the view wants to be as big as its parent (minus padding)
```

> But with this i lost drawer open-close button (Three horizontal lines).

The reason is that in your `ActionBarDrawerToggle` you didn't pass a toolbar into it, so you lost the drawer open-close button.

```
// NOTE: Make sure you pass in a valid toolbar reference.  ActionBarDrawToggle() does not require it
// and will not render the hamburger icon without it.  
var drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, toolbar, Resource.String.drawer_open, Resource.String.drawer_close);
```

[Here is my complete code about Drawerlayout](https://github.com/aixiaozi/DrawerLayoutDemo) and it works fine.

Comment: Thanks you very much